# Why is my jade index page blank?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm broadly following this tutorial on Express, Mongo and Jade, and although I've successfully fetched back some data from mongo, but jade isn't rendering my page.
http://blog.ijasoneverett.com/2013/03/a-sample-app-with-node-js-express-and-mongodb-part-1/

Snippets are:

app.js:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    employeeProvider.findAll(function(error, emps) {
        // adding logging here shows that 'title' and 'emps' are correctly populated 
        res.render('index', { title:'Employees', employees:emps });
    });
});
```

layout.jade:

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title= title
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    body
        block content
```

index.jade:

```
extends layout

block content    
    h1= title
    div
        each employee in employees
            div.employee
                div.created_at= employee.created_at
                div.title= employee.title
                div.name= employee.name
```

When I extract the source from the page displayed in the browser, it just shows this:

`<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Employees</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css"></head><body></body></html>`

In fact, nothing I put in jade.index to simplify it seems to get rendered. eg this also renders a blank page:

index.jade:

```
extends layout

block content    
    h1= title
```

Comment: I think the files should be called `index.jade` and `layout.jade`, not `jade.index` etc.

Comment: indeed you're right, and they are called index.jade etc. I transposed as I typed up my question. I'll edit the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check again the tutorial and follow it (realy), since your code is diferent...

http://blog.ijasoneverett.com/2013/03/a-sample-app-with-node-js-express-and-mongodb-part-1/

The `index.jade` should be:

```
extends layout

block content
    h1= title
    #employees
        - each employee in employees
          div.employee
            div.created_at= employee.created_at
            div.title= employee.title 
            div.name= employee.name
        a(href="/employee/new")!= "Add New Employee"
```

There are some needed css over `#employees` and
the each loop needs a `-` before itself.

Comment: I started with that code but it didnt work. I've seen examples elsewhere where the - is not used. In any case, my 2nd example (where the code is basically just 'h1= title') should print something to the screen, but doesn't.